# Как массово изменить текст для элементов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я хочу взять текст из одних элементов и поместить в другой блок.

Вот как сейчас: https://jsfiddle.net/m450tpjm/

Вот код:

```
$('ul li').each(function() {
    var listText = $(this).find('a').text();
    $('.another p span').html(listText);
});
```

Дело в том что, текст идет только с последнего листа, а не по очереди ко всем.
Каким образом можно исправить эту проблему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема была в том, что каждому `.another p span` он присваивал значение текущего `ul li a`, то есть в конце итерации по `each` он присвоил всем `span'am` `Item 4`

```js
$('ul li').each(function(id) {
 var listText = $(this).find('a').text();
 $('.another p span').eq(id).html(listText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>

<hr>

<div class="another">
  <p>Paragraph: <span></span></p>
  <p>Paragraph: <span></span></p>
  <p>Paragraph: <span></span></p>
  <p>Paragraph: <span></span></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('ul li').each(function(i, item) {
    $('.another p span:eq('+i+')').html($(item).text());
});
```